# How to make pymongo's find() return a list?

Tags: pymongo

Pymongo returns a cursor with it I am able to iterate over the results and append their documents to a list. Is there a way to get the result documents in a list directly?
Thanks

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The following code will convert the entire result set (`Cursor`) into a `list`:

```
myresults = list(mydb.mycollection.find())
```

This is fine for relatively small result sets, as you are pulling everything into memory.

Comment: what if i have bigger results? what is recommended?

Comment: @Jaziel_Inc if it's large then you can iterate over it e.g. `first_doc = next( mydb.mycollection.find() )`, where `first_doc` would be a dictionary

Comment: For more rows: `c = mydb.mycollection.find(); first_5_rows = [next(c) for _ in range(5)]`

Comment: @AlexG thank you, so the other option is to iterate over the cursor.

Comment: Thank you! Took too long to figure out that you can only iterate the Cursor once and need to convert it to a list otherwise!