# How to make mongodump start over from the beginning?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I'm using mongodump to migrate a 200+ GB database to `directoryPerDB`. In the process of trying to test a smaller dataset for finding the optimal number of parallel dumps I could run ([per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50385803/2566029)), my mongodump keeps resuming from where I left off.

So if I cancel it at 10% and then re-run it, it picks right back at 10%.

I've tried deleting the dump folder, exporting to an archive file, changing my target and current folders, and restarting mongod, but I can't find any way to force mongodump to start over from the beginning on the collection.

Thanks in advance for your help!